# Groovy Script - Logback configuration unawaited behaviour

Tags: grails, groovy, logback

I want to use `Logback` as my logging framework within Grails. therefore I set up everything in place to work but my implementation fails on the configuration file itself. the reason is, as I guess, somewhere whithin the scoping of Groovy Script but I'm not able to figure it out...

if I define my `String` properties without any identifier which I want to use later I get a warning that it may not be accessed. For example:

```
LOG_DIR = 'c:/temp/myproject/logs/'
BACKUP_DIR = LOG_DIR + 'backup/'

appender('F_MAIN', RollingFileAppender) {
  file = LOG_DIR + 'test.log'
  rollingPolicy(FixedWindowRollingPolicy) {
    fileNamePattern = BACKUP_DIR + 'test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip'
    // .... and so on
  }
}
```

I get the following error message from Logback, which I'm pretty sure is indicating that both `LOG_DIR` and `BACKUP_DIR` can not be reached:

```
13:33:32,036 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.AppenderDelegate@6fd00b - Appender [F_MAIN] of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender] has no appplicable [LOG_DIR] property 
13:33:32,068 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ComponentDelegate@788ac3 - Component  of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy] has no appplicable [BACKUP_DIR] property
```

I also tried the following approach by declaring both variables with the `@Field` tag, but it still does not work:

```
@Field String LOG_DIR = 'c:/temp/myproject/logs/'
@Field String BACKUP_DIR = LOG_DIR + 'backup/'

appender('F_MAIN', RollingFileAppender) {
  file = LOG_DIR + 'test.log'
  rollingPolicy(FixedWindowRollingPolicy) {
    fileNamePattern = BACKUP_DIR + 'test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip'
    // .... and so on
  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you use the Grails logback plugin or this is a Spring DSL from the resources.groovy file?

Comment: @drorb as you can see here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-logback/issues/3 the Grails Logback Plugin cannot be installed. this is neither a Spring DSL from the `resources.groovy` file, instead it is just a Groovy Script (`LogbackConfig.groovy`) placed within the `grails-app/conf` folder which is copied to a defined location on WAR deployment...

Comment: LogbackConfig.groovy will be treated by Grails as a configuration file, which means you need something which will respond to the 'appender' DSL

Comment: @drob no, it doesn't. this is a valid configuration file for Logback, as Logback is able to deal with Groovy config files so I won't need to stick to the appender DSL per se ;). in the meanwhile I already found the solution and I will post it here along with some explaination if it's of any help. thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh my!
after searching and a lot of trial/error I found the solution and it was so close and definitely seems obvious now: I had to declare both variables with `def`, so now they are visible throughout the whole script ;)

For example, this is working code:

```
def LOG_DIR = 'c:/temp/myproject/logs/'
def BACKUP_DIR = LOG_DIR + 'backup/'

appender('F_MAIN', RollingFileAppender) {
  file = LOG_DIR + 'test.log'
  rollingPolicy(FixedWindowRollingPolicy) {
    fileNamePattern = BACKUP_DIR + 'test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip'
    // .... and so on
  }
}
```

now, I'm also able to use a function like this within my script:

```
def createFilename(String directory, String name, boolean isBackupFile) {
  String filename = ''
  if(isBackupFile) {
    filename = "${directory}backup/MyProject-${name}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip"
  } else {
    filename = "${directory}MyProject-${name}.log"
  }
  return filename
}

def fileAppenderLog = createFilename(LOG_DIR, 'output', false)
def fileAppenderLogBackup = createFilename(LOG_DIR, 'output', true)

appender('F_MAIN', RollingFileAppender) {
  file = fileAppenderLog
  rollingPoliciy(FixedWindowRollingPolicy) {
    fileNamePattern = fileAppenderLogBackup
    // .... and so on
  }
}
```

which is pretty useful, I think :), especially if you want to declare a bunch of different logfiles and even if you want to declare temporary logfiles which are created when Logback is rescanning this file ...